# Restricting users to certain sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, access

I am very new to the world/maze of SharePoint online permissions, so I have a fairly basic question.

Inside SharePoint online, is it possible to restrict a user from accessing certain sites?

Let us say that we have two sites:

```
company.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteA
company.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteB
```

Is it possible for an admin to set permissions such that a user can only see and access one of the two sites?

Answer (score 1):

You simply would not add them to the sites you did not want them to have access to.

Answer (score 0):

This video is a very good primer for permissions in SharePoint, hopes it will answer your question.
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=A48pm46zyTw

Answer (score 0):

By default, for users except site collection administrator, if you don't share the site with them, or add users into the site's groups, the users will not have access to the site. So, if you don't want users to access a site, just do nothing for the user at the site.